Sarama Kafka ConsumerGroup implementation
I have a decent experience working with kafka and python using confluent kafka library. Recently I had to shift towards golang and use sarama library with it.
And I can not understand how ConsumerGroups work in sarama. In python it was fairly straightforward. You just create a consumer object with a group id defined. Define on_assign callback for partition rebalancing and you're good to go. But I am unable to understand it in sarama. There are not many tutorials available to understand the flow.
Can someone explain to me the flow of consumerGroups in sarama. And what would be the best way to implement a consumerGroup that can have one or multiple consumers in it that process the messages and saves them to a destination s3 location. Any tips or resources link will be appreciated


There are not many tutorials available to understand the flow.

Where did you look?
https://github.com/IBM/sarama/blob/main/consumer_group_example_test.go

have one or multiple consumers in it that process the messages

Start multiple processes of the same code

decent experience working with kafka and python using confluent kafka library.

Confluent also has a golang client following similar design as their Python one

saves them to a destination s3 location

Kafka Connect / Redpanda Connect / Conduit / Vector / Apache Camel KConnect / Apache Gobblin / Pinterest Secor / Apache Nifi, etc. would all be better, IMO, to just write to S3, as the code already exists for this, and you only need config files to specify the bucket and topics. Don't reinvent the wheel... Confluent maintains the S3 sink connector
You could also look at Warpstream which directly replaces the actual kafka brokers with proxy services that read/write from S3 with any kafka compatible client

I did found this consumer group example code but I was not able to understand the flow. Also, it's not possible for me to change the library to confluent-kafka or intoduce any 3rd party tools like Nifi, as it is beyond my control in the current place of work. Btw thanks a lot for the answer and do let me know if you've any other resources that can help me understand sarama's flow a bit better.

@TaimoorAbbasi How is changing the go.mod file to use confluent-kafka-go beyond your control? If your coworkers are forcing you to use a library that is more work then they are wrong... In any case, please clarify what exactly you don't understand about the flow. You create a config... The group accepts that config. Then you tell the group to consume a list of topics with a record handler, not a "specific consumer". To actually run a consumer group, you start multiple processes of the code

I tried reading this example but I could understand how the messages are returned i.e. what this goroutine is suppose to do. In cofluent-kafka the consume function will return the list of messages that you can process but here it only returns error that confuses me. And again Thanks a lot for your help.

And if i understand correctly, Setup function will run when the partition rebalancing is done. The Cleanup function will run once a new consumer joins the group and rebalancing is triggered. And we will have to implement a ConsumeClaim function for the message handler interface to process that messages.

@TaimoorAbbasi Why are you looking at the more complicated example? See https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/IBM/sarama#example-ConsumerGroup

This one looks a lot simpler and i gives a better overview as well. I'll try to implement according to this now. Once I get comfortable I'll try to understand that complex example. Thanks a lot for your assistance

@TaimoorAbbasi That's the same example I linked in the answer

My bad I confused it with the one that I was looking into earlier. Sorry for that!
